# Google Not Indexing my site

Tags: google-search-console

It wont index any of my pages. I have each registered user created in a folder with files cloned inside of it. Though, google doesnt pick up any of these folders. Site has been live since February and almost all of the pages have been "fetched as Google" manually that have been indexed.
Only 25 of hundreds upon hundreds. Any ideas?

Comment: Do the pages have a robots.txt file specifying they shouldn't be indexed?

Comment: Nope. In fact I added a robots.txt just a few days ago. Take a look http://lit.life/robots.txt